# How to activate bootstrap DatePicker through icon

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I activate my bootstrap DatePicker through clicking an icon?

My HTML code is:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker">  
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" id="cal2"></i></span>
```

and the script  is:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to activate my datepicker by clicking on the icon but it is not working.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which datepicker? There are many forks of bootstrap-datepicker; are you using the eternicode version, the eyecon version, or something else?

Answer (score 12):

```
<input type="text" id="my-datepicker" class="datepicker">  
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" id="cal2"></i></span>

<script type="text/javascript">"
   $('#cal2').click(function(){
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#my-datepicker").datepicker().focus();
       });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can get it done like this, but there is a small change in your html.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="tb_date">  
<label class="add-on" for="tb_date">
  <i class="icon-calendar" id="cal2"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: Excellent answer !

Answer (score 4):

From [**docs**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/), Wrap your datepicker `textbox` with **`div`** like

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" /> 
       <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" id="cal2"></i></span>
</div>
```

Then attached the datepicker event with `div`'s id like

```
$("#dp3").datepicker();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GX82L/7/)

Comment: datepicker don't go away. It remains open.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

> .datepicker('show') Show the datepicker.

Just use the click event to show your datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true,
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You're wrong, OP is talking about **bootstrap datepicker** whereas you're answer is for `jQuery datepicker`.

Answer (score 0):

In the version of 1.2.0, It has done as default:

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox